# Создание Dockerfile

Tags: docker, latex

На данный момент у меня есть такой dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.10

RUN apt-get install texlive
RUN apt install texinfo
RUN apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended
Run apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra
Run apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
```

Задача состоит в том ,чтобы создать dockerfile, который  компилирует latex в pdf.В приватном репозитории хранится файл latex.Как мне в dockerfile получить доступ к этому latex файлу и вывести полученный pdf файл в заданную папку?

Answer (score 1):

В Dockerfile описывается процесс создания образа, а не программа. Максимум что вы можете сделать, это написать скрипт выполняющую вашу задачу с использованием зависимостей, которые вы указали в RUN, и поместить его в контейнер с помощью COPY